# How to make a log plot in Julia?

Tags: plot, julia

Is there a simple way to make a log-log plot or semilog plot in Julia?  This [link](https://plot.ly/julia/log-plot/) provides a sort of clunky way to do it, but given the general ethos of Julia I suspect there's a shorter way.

Comment: I suggest that you use [`Plots.jl`](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/) package to make plots with `Plotly` so that you can plot much easier and switch to other backends(e.g. PyPlot, GR etc.) without a change in your code. @Yly's answer shows how you can make log plot using `Plots.jl`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As described [here](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/attributes/#magic-arguments), you can accomplish this with magic arguments `yaxis=:log` or `xaxis=:log`.

```
using Plots 
x = 1:100
# log-log plot
plot(x.^2, xaxis=:log, yaxis=:log)
# semilog plot 
plot(x.^2, xaxis=:log)
```

Comment: how can achieve that x axis is log10, while y is log2?

Comment: The updated syntax as of May 2023: `xscale=:log10` and `yscale=:log10`. Other possibilities are: `ln`, `log2`.